# OpenFL take input from device gyroscope

Tags: android, ios, orientation, haxe, openfl

Okay, so I am working on a mobile app in [OpenFL](http://www.openfl.org/) and [Haxe](http://haxe.org/). I would like to gather input from the gyroscope, or more specifically about the orientation of the phone. I have searched the openfl docs, and google for some kind of documentation or examples on this sort of thing. I had no luck there and would like to know if anyone could point me toward some.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make a new Accelerometer:

   ```
   private var _acc:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
   ```
2. Add an event listener to it:

   ```
   _acc.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, updateAcc);
   ```
3. Listen to results:

   ```
   private function updateAcc(Event:AccelerometerEvent):Void 
   {
       trace("x:" + Event.accelerationX);
       trace("y:" + Event.accelerationY);
       trace("z:" + Event.accelerationZ);
   }
   ```

Note than iOS accelerometer values are inverted.